# Figure won't go half way down page

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

Hi I'm writing a thesis and my set-up is essentially using my universities template where there's a master .tex file that then accesses `\input{Chapter}` to make each chapter.

In my chapters the general format is text text text with figures at the end **each figure on a separate page with it's caption underneath and all centered and at the middle of the page**.

I have one figure that is smaller than the rest and when I use my typical commands Latex puts it on the previous page underneath the previous figure (squeezes it in with caption and all) so to circumvent this I use the `\clearpage` command but now the figure appears centered but not in the middle of the page. Any ideas?

```
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth,height=.9\textheight,keepaspectratio]{Fig3.pdf}
\caption[Figure one caption for preamble]{Figure one caption on page it appears.}
%\label{fig:filenameoffigurehere}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{\fill}

\clearpage
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth,height=.9\textheight,keepaspectratio]{Fig4.pdf}
\caption[Figure 2 caption for preamble]{Figure 2 caption on page it appears.}
%\label{fig:filenameoffigurehere}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{\fill}
```

And my package list is (ever changing) as follows:

```
    \usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[square,super,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\setcellgapes[b]{-3pt}
\newcommand{\mca}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mcb}[1]{\multicolumn{4}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
```

Comment: the answer is not to use `[h]` as shown but also note that your multiple settings of `\topskip` looks wrong, certainly only one is needed as it affects the rest of the document but this will mess up the text baseline for all following pages unless you set it back somewhere,

Comment: loading inputenc without specifying an encoding does noting useful

Answer (score 1):

See, if this is of some help:

```
\documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-7]
\begin{figure}[p]% <--- 
\vspace*{\fill}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth,height=.9\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
\caption[Figure one caption for preamble]{Figure one caption on page it appears.}
%\label{fig:filenameoffigurehere}
    \vspace*{\fill}
\end{figure}
\clearpage% <--- 
    \lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure}[p]% <--- 
\vspace*{\fill}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth,height=.9\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
\caption[Figure 2 caption for preamble]{Figure 2 caption on page it appears.}
%\label{fig:filenameoffigurehere}
    \vspace*{\fill}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I use figure option `p` and put `\clearpage` after each figure.